# В чем смысл вложенных друг в друга инструкций synchronized?

Tags: java, синхронизация

Встретил вот такой [пример](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31953201/) *(стр 422)*

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        synchronized(t) {
            synchronized(t) {
                System.out.printIn("made it!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Далее, видимо, объяснение на мой вопрос, но для меня не вполне очевидное.

> Вывод этой программы имеет вид
>
> ```
> made it!
> ```
>
> Обратите внимание, что эта программа оказалась бы в состоянии
>   взаимоблокировки, если бы один поток не мог многократно блокировать
>   монитор.

Инструкция `synchronized` понятна, захватывает блокировку, выполняет тело инструкции, освобождает блокировку.

А в чем смысл вложенных друг в друга инструкций `synchronized`? Как происходит их (инструкций) взаимодействие между собой?

Comment: собственно пример показывает, что один потом может делать сколько угодно вложенных `synchronized` и не зависнет при этом. О чем говорит выведенное сообщение. Если бы это не работало, но программа бы подвисла на втором `synchronized` пока не освободится `t`, но так как он может освободиться только выйдя из первого - то получилась блокировка самого себя

Comment: В данном случае только в демонстрации. Никакого взаимодействия нет, каждый блок захватывает блокировку, ничего не зная о внешнем или вложенном блоке. Ну, на этом уровне, в кишочках JVM разница есть.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Данный пример призван показать, что один поток может делать сколько угодно вложенных `synchronized` и не зависнет при этом. О чем и говорит выведенное сообщение.

Если бы это не работало, то программа бы подвисла на втором `synchronized` пока не освободится `t`, но так как он может освободиться только выйдя из первого - то получилась бы блокировка самого себя